# Change Domain Controller Name

Tags: active-directory

I would like to change our Domain controller  name is it
possible?

Our Dns Name xyz.local

and Netbios name XYZ i would like change to ABC.

Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to change the name of the DOMAIN or of a DOMAIN CONTROLLER?

If you want to rename a DOMAIN CONTROLLER, just do it like you would do on any other Windows machine: from the System properties. After renaming, be sure to reboot it at least two times, in order for the domain DNS to be properly updated.

If you instead want to rename a DOMAIN, this can be accomplished, but it's a little more complex; here is the reference for it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786120(WS.10).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Just change it the same way you would change any XP/2003 name.

Control Panel -> System -> Computer Name

See http://www.petri.co.il/windows_2003_domain_controller_rename.htm (the no.1 result in google for change DC name...) for a visual guide.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that the Domain Controller renaming tool is only available if your Domain Functional level is set to Windows Server 2003 or higher.